# Django : Connection refused to live_server_url

Tags: python, django, selenium, docker, testing

I'm using docker, selenium, and Django.
I just realised i was doing my tests on my production database ; while i wanted to test on `StaticLiveServerTestCase` self-generated database.

I tried to follow [that tutorial](https://marcgibbons.com/post/selenium-in-docker/)

```
@override_settings(ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*'])
class BaseTestCase(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    host = '0.0.0.0'

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        cls.selenium = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://hub:4444/wd/hub',
            desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME,
        )
        cls.selenium.implicitly_wait(5)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.quit()
        super().tearDownClass()


class MyTest(BaseTestCase):

    def test_simple(self):
        self.selenium.get(self.live_server_url)
```

I've no error trying to connect to the chrome-hub, but when i try to print my page_source, i'm not on my django app but on a chrome error message. Here is a part :

```
<div class="error-code" jscontent="errorCode" jstcache="7">ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED</div>
```

I'm using docker-compose 1. Selenium.yml:

```
chrome:
  image: selenium/node-chrome:3.11.0-dysprosium
  volumes:
    - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
  links:
    - hub
  environment:
    HUB_HOST: hub
    HUB_PORT: '4444'

hub:
  image: selenium/hub:3.11.0-dysprosium
  ports:
    - "4444:4444"
  expose:
    - "4444"

app:
  links:
    - hub
```

I guess i did something wrong in my docker-compose file, but i don't manage to figure out what.

Thanks in advance !

PS : `live_server_url` = `http://localhost:8081`

Comment: I guess your app has to connect to `command_executor='http://hub:4444/wd/hub'` instead of `command_executor='http://selenium:4444/wd/hub'`

Comment: I've no error trying to connect to the chrome-hub. But you're right it wouldn't work, I did a bad copy past, gonna edit it

Answer (score 1):

You need to put container_name of the container that is running Django/the tests as host when using docker-compose, i.e.

```
host = 'app'
```

For a more detailed discussion see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32408429/running-django-tests-with-selenium-in-docker)

Comment: This was the simplest solution for me! Didn't had to modify any part of my code, just add this under the class declaration and everything started working.