# Run Selenium tests for Django project in Gitlab CI : ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on get live_server_url

Tags: python, django, selenium, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to have GitLab CI run (with a shared runner) Selenium tests on my Django project every time commits are pushed to the repo on Gitlab.com.

gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: python:3.8.5

services:
  - selenium/standalone-chrome:latest

cache:
  paths:
    - ~/.cache/pip/

before_script:
  - python -V
  - python -m pip install --force-reinstall pip==18.1
  - pip install -r requirements.txt

test:
  script:
    - python manage.py test
```

tests.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

@override_settings(DEBUG=True)
class CreateNewProjectTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        selenium_url = 'http://selenium__standalone-chrome:4444/wd/hub'
        self.selenium = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor=selenium_url,
            desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
        super(CreateNewProjectTestCase, self).setUp()

    def test_create(self):
        selenium = self.selenium
        selenium.get(self.live_server_url)
```

However, when the pipeline job executes, I get the following error (connection refused) on `selenium.get(self.live_server_url)`, resulting in a job's failure:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/builds/uchem/projectmanagment-django-heroku/projects/tests.py", line 54, in test_create
    selenium.get(self.live_server_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.75)
```

Is there something I am missing? I think the URL is correct and I saw answers quite similar to this.

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601185/django-connection-refused-to-live-server-url), but not exactly because the gitlab-ci.yaml is different yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As done in [this tutorial](https://gitlab.com/johanv/codeception-ci-demo), I managed to get it working by specifying a certain version of Chrome (`standalone-chrome:3.141.59-oxygen`) instead of `standalone-chrome:latest`.

I have no clue why this works though.